# Program crashes, because of std::rotate_copy

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, rotation

I am trying to display two cams next to each other, rotated by 90°. Displaying both cams works fine, but if I want to rotate the cams, the program crashes.
The camera is read with a QByteArray and shown with the QCamera variable.
You can choose which camera is displayed in which viewfinder, so it has a code like this:

```
QActionGroup *videoDevicesGroup = new QActionGroup(this);
videoDevicesGroup->setExclusive(true);
foreach(const QByteArray &deviceName, QCamera::availableDevices()) {
    QString description = camera->deviceDescription(deviceName);
    QAction *videoDeviceAction = new QAction(description, videoDevicesGroup);
    videoDeviceAction->setCheckable(true);
    videoDeviceAction->setData(QVariant(deviceName));
    if (cameraDevice.isEmpty()) {
        cameraDevice = deviceName;
        videoDeviceAction->setChecked(true);
    }
    ui->menuDevices->addAction(videoDeviceAction);
}
    connect(videoDevicesGroup, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), SLOT(updateCameraDevice(QAction*)));
if (cameraDevice.isEmpty())
{
    camera = new QCamera;
}
else
{
    camera = new QCamera(cameraDevice);
}
connect(camera, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QCamera::State)), this, SLOT(updateCameraState(QCamera::State)));
connect(camera, SIGNAL(error(QCamera::Error)), this, SLOT(displayCameraError()));
camera->setViewfinder(ui->viewfinder);
updateCameraState(camera->state());
camera->start();
```

Now I'm trying to rotate this cam with the command:

```
std::roate_copy(cameraDevice.constBegin(), cameraDevice.constEnd(), cameraDevice.constEnd, reverse.begin());
camera = new QCamera(reverse);
```

But when I try to start the program the program crashes, without any errors.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you supposed to pass the `cameraDevice.constEnd` function (i.e. not calling it)? Have you created enough entries in `reverse` to fit all entries from `cameraDevice` (they won't be created automatically)?

Comment: The problem is, I don't know what to write for the middle iterator to rotate the camera by 90°

Comment: @AlexFarber It compiled with no errors. Then the Apllication Output started to blink (it does everytime a program starts) and then there was an errormessage that the program crashed, but not a message by qt, it was by windows

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how can I check how many entries i have in reverse and in cameraDevice? The cameraDevice has all it entries from the Webcam, is there a code to check?

Comment: If `reverse` is a *standard* container, then you can use e.g. [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to get an iterator that automatically appends to the end of the container. If `reverse` is a Qt container, you have to look through their documentation to see if they have something similar (they probably do). Also read the documentation for the container you use to see how to set the number of items in the container beforehand.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Everything seems to be ok..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding on what `std::rotate_copy` does.

`std::rotate_copy` takes a range of data and shifts it as it copies into the location pointed to by the `result` iterator.

This won't rotate a camera. It just shifts and copies ranges: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate_copy

**EDIT:**

Think about it this way say I have: `std::string("wroybgivb");`
Now say I do `str::rotate_copy` and I pick the "y" as my middle the `std::string` that I copied into will contain "ybgivbwro".

Now think about that like I was working with a 3X3 image and each character represented a color:

> `wro    ybg`
>   `ybg => ivb`
>   `ivb    wro`

Note that this is doing a linear array rotation (position shifting). I can never pick a middle such that rows will become columns and columns will become rows.

**PS:**

OK so say that you knew the width of the image, and assigned it to the variable `width`. You can do something like this to rotate 90° clockwise:

```
for(int x = 0; x < size; ++x){
    output[width - 1 - i / width + (i % width) * width] = input[i];
}
```

To understand this you need to understand indexing a linear array as though it's a 2D array.
Use this to access the *x coordinate:* `i % width`
Use this to access the *y coordinate:* `(i / width) * width`

Now you need to take those indices and rotate them still inside a linear array.
Use this to access the *x coordinate:* `width - 1 - i / width`
Use this to access the *y coordinate:* `(i % width) * width`

Comment: Yes but the data of the camera are saved in a QByteArray and if I rotate the array the image has to be rotated. Or are there differens in an Array and a camera array? In the QByteArray there are just the information for every pixel saved.

Comment: @Der_Pätti Edited to help explain.

Comment: I see... But are you even able to rotate a QCamera? Or is it possible in c++ because I've tried many things and nothing worked...

Comment: @Der_Pätti One more edit. If you have further questions about rotating a linear array, you should probably accept this answer and we start a new question; cause we're pretty far off the original question.